# заменить input text на textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть множество полей ввода input text, которые я хочу заменять на textarea если человек входит с телефона. Как заменить я знаю, но как в замененную textarea передать параметры data-answer что бы получались `<textarea data-answer="">`?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
        $(this).after('<textarea></textarea>').remove()
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-answer="text 1"/>
<input type="text" data-answer="text 2"/>
<input type="text" data-answer="text 3"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно необходимо сделать отдельный шаблон для мобильной версии.

Но ниже ответ на текущую реализацию.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
        $(this).after($('<textarea></textarea>').attr('data-answer', $(this).attr('data-answer'))).remove()
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-answer="text 1"/>
<input type="text" data-answer="text 2"/>
<input type="text" data-answer="text 3"/>
```

Comment: спасибо. а может есть какой то способ не заменяя на textarea как то расширить input text? проблема в том, что пользователям нужно вводить предложения и на компьютере все смотрится хорошо, но в телефоне уже все предложение не видно когда вводишь.

Comment: @akasergej CSS стили: [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: но только горизонтально без переноса на след строку, как описал выше @AlexanderBragin

Comment: ну так то я расширю, но текст ведь все равно не будет видно

Comment: Можно попробовать без JS (jQuery) сделать попробовать через media query: `display: block|none;`: прятать input и показывать textarea. Но будьте также с этим аккуратны как и замена элементов через JS, потому что пользователь может уже заполнил поле, и вдруг решил устройства перевернуть или браузер по ширине уменьшить мышкой (если на ПК) и у вас при «переходе» весь ввод «слетит». Я бы на вашем месте на одном типе элементов остановился. Что у вас там за верстка такая особая?.. P.S.: Ну либо ещё про value в JS не забыть «передать».

Comment: Ничего необычного. Придется воспользоваться примеров выше с jquery и с помощью php обнаружения мобильного браузера выводить скрипт заменяющий.

Comment: @akasergej если вы PHP определяете мобильную версию, то  не проще ли, прям в шаблоне и менять на textarea?

Comment: @akasergej вот так по-маленьку и выясняются всегда подробности :)

Comment: было бы проще, но у меня сотни этих input' ов, в ручную переписывать их все для отдельного шаблона с textarea не вариант :/

Comment: @akasergej если фреймворк, сделайте свой SuperTextInput декоратор или подобное и реюзайте где угодно. Если проект на кастомном фрейворке, то шаблончик заведите с параметрами.

Answer (score 0):

Аттрибут `data-answer` можно хранить в родительском контейнере, а `input` и `textarea` показывать/скрывать при помощи взаимоисключающих `@media` например.

```css
.input-container .input-media {
  display: none;
}
@media all and (orientation: portrait) {
  .input-container .media-portrait {
     display: block;
  }
}
@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
  .input-container .media-landscape {
     display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container" data-answer="Answer 3">
  <input type="text" class="input-media media-landscape" />
  <textarea class="input-media media-portrait"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: В таком случае есть вероятность, что введенные данные пользователя потеряются (как писал ниже в комментариях)... Но ещё больший нюанс это будет с аналитикой форм :)

Comment: значение textarea всегда будет отсылатся постом, если есть тот же name, поскольку ниже.

Comment: @tcpack4 ну так и не нужно называть эти поля одинаково. И вообще не факт, что эти поля должны быть внутри формы для отправки на сервер - в вопросе нет никаких `name=".."`. Может быть при изменении значений в `input` и `textarea` будет заполняться какой-то массив или `<input type="hidden" />` внутри какой-нибудь другой скрытой от пользователя формы. Это всё зависит от многих факторов.

Comment: @tcpack4 ещё можно использовать `<textarea>` всегда, а для "однострочного поля ввода" применить к ней `resize: none; white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: hidden; height: ...px` опять же через `@media`. Тогда и менять ничего не придётся.